# Why camelcase not installed?

Tags: python, installation, pip, package, camelcasing

i try to install camelcase in my python project.
`pip install camelcase`

but when i want to use the package, pylance give me this error:
Import "camelcase" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)

and i tried to install camelcase again and pip said: 
Requirement already satisfied: camelcase in /home/mohammad-hgh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.2)[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Yes, I will not upload photos anymore.  Thank you for your guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happened to me, you just had to restart visual studio code after installing a new package. Try restarting VSCODE and if that does not work try `pip uninstall camelcase` and then `pip install camelcase`

Comment: It still gives an error!!

Comment: @MohammadNazari did you try to re-install it and THEN restart VSCODE?

Comment: Yes, and it finally worked