# IDE can't find path to flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I can't seem to use flask for simple applications, it just cant find it for some reason. Not sure if I have installed flask in the wrong location on my pc. If someone could help me out it's driving me insane and questioning my life choices haha[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZV4l.png)

I've tried uninstalling it and redoing it but didn't work and tried moving the flask folder where my code folders are as well still didn't work

Comment: run `"C:/Users/Ben ../../.../WindowsApps/python3.11.exe" -m pip install flask` replace all the `..` with the correct path that you have in your terminal output

Comment: Try `pip uninstall flask` then `pip install flask` and then RESTART VSCode. Read my answer on a question similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267939/why-camelcase-not-installed/73267970#73267970